# Render a styled and structured submit input button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a system and the front-end guy, who isn't me, and got this strange buttons:

```
<a class="button" href="#">
    <span class="txt">  submit </span>
    <span class="bg-button"></span>
</a>
```

How can I render this structure on a form's submit input?

```
f.input
```

just renders the input. No real way to edit it the html structure. Can I pass in a block or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can have that html with the `link_to` helper.
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

what actually happens here is that it is not a form button, but an `<a href>` tag that is styled like a button.

so you can have in your .html.erb file:

```
<%= link_to '#', { class: :button } do %>
  <span class="txt">submit</span>
  <span class="bg-button"></span>
<% end %>
```

and then catch the click to that button with a js handler and send the request to the server.

Answer (score -1):

```
f.submit, 'Submit', :class => "txt button bg-button"
```